# i created a signed android application and installed it but it doesn't run on my phone

Tags: android, eclipse

i have created an unsigned apk which i have signed with a keystore thru eclipse itself. As of now I've heard that eclipse automatically zipaligns signed application and the application shows no errors and runs smoothly. but when I moved the project apk on my phone, it gets installed but doesn't run. the screen flashes for a fraction of second and I'm back to my homescreen. Is there a problem in my phone or in the signing process? Is there any other step to be performed after signing an apk?

Comment: You write "the application shows no errors and runs smoothly"

who said this.. This is completely wrong, Unsigned apps should be usable generally but do require lowering the security level and Signed have high security level so used for publishing the application.

Signed doesn't means that your error containing application run smoothly.

Comment: Have you enabled proguard ?